# Query to transform unknown number of rows to unknown number of columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, crosstab

I'm been looking for hours at different options (PIVOT, CROSS JOIN etc...) to transform an unknown number of rows to an unknown number of columns with SQL server 2008 and I'm even more lost than before I started.

Basically I have 3 tables:

**Role**

```
|id| name|
| 1|role1|
| 2|role2|
| 3|role3|
```

**Action**

```
|id|  name |
| 1|action1|
| 2|action2|
| 3|action3|
```

**RoleAction**

```
|roleId| actionId|
|   1  |    1    |
|   1  |    2    |
|   2  |    1    |
|   3  |    2    |
```

Is there anyway to build a query or SP that would transform the result of a `LEFT JOIN` to a nice "pivot" table like this:

```
|actionId|actionName|role1|role2|role3|.....|role n|
|   1    | action1  |  1  |  1  |  0  |.....|   0  |
|   2    | action2  |  1  |  0  |  1  |.....|   0  |
|   3    | action3  |  0  |  0  |  0  |.....|   0  |
|   .    |    .     |  .  |  .  |  .  |.....|   .  |
|   .    |    .     |  .  |  .  |  .  |.....|   .  |
|   n    | action n |  0  |  0  |  0  |.....|   0  |
```

Many many thanks for your help!

Comment: Search this site for "dynamic pivot" - the pattern you're after has been solved many times here.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks a lot, I have now managed to do it. It was just a matter of knowing how it was called. I'm loving "dynamic pivot"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big thank you to Aaron for putting me on the right track!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.RoleActionsPivot
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  Action.ActionId, Action.ActionName , Role.RoleId, Role.RoleName
INTO    #tmpRoleAction
FROM    Action LEFT JOIN RoleActions ON Action.ActionId = RoleAction.ActionId 
    LEFT JOIN Role ON RoleAction.RoleId = Role.RoleId

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(RoleName) 
            FROM #tmpRoleAction
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ActionId, ActionName, ' + @cols + ' FROM

    (SELECT * FROM #tmpRoleAction) x

    PIVOT  ( max(RoleId) for RoleName in (' + @cols + ')) p '


execute(@query)
```